# Reference request: analytic proof of the Ascoli-Arzelà theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, alternative-proof

All the proofs of the Ascoli-Arzelà theorem I've encountered so far are really topology dependent, by which I mean the rely deeply on topology concepts such as compactness, open covers, sub covers and so on.

However, I've been told about the existence of a completely analytic proof of this theorem that I have failed to find. Can anyone provide a reference for the proof I am looking for? Thanks in advance.

The version of theorem I'm using is the following:

> Let $\{f_n\}_{n \in A}$ be an infinite family of uniformly bounded and equicontinuous functions defined in a bounded set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and mapping into $\mathbb{R}^m$. Then, there exists a sequence $\{f_k\}_{k\in A}$ that converges uniformly in $E$.

Comment: Have you looked at Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*?

Comment: What version of the Ascoli-Arzelà are you talking about? The statement itself in the general version uses the topological concepts. I would not expect that the proof can be completely analytic in such version.

Comment: @Jack I've edited the question with the version of the theorem I'm using.

Comment: @TedShifrin I haven't, but I'll take a look and see what I can find. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't exist in that book by Rudin, but it does in "Real and Complex Analysis". Yet the language is "tainted" with topological concepts and, besides this, it is given for complex functions. The proof though is not that messy and without much topology.

Comment: Do you mean you want to argue the theorem without relying on compactness arguments for sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$? It is my understanding that Arzela-Ascoli was one of the first uses of such arguments, at least in a sequential form. Equicontinuity is the glue that allows a reduction to functions on a countable dense subset, where a Cantor diagonalization argument can be used to obtain pointwise convergence for a subsequence of functions at every point of the countable dense subset. If you want to assume a countable dense subset and equicontinuity, then you can make the argument.